# How to push array within another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to store sub category name and products related to that particular subcategory in array.

Below is my code,

```
f ($sub_category->num_rows > 1) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_category)) {
    $subcategory_id = $row['sub_cat_id'];
    $subcategory_name['sub_category_name'][] = $row['sub_cat_name'];             
    $sql_subrec = "SELECT es_product_description.name AS prod_name FROM es_product_to_category LEFT JOIN es_product_description ON es_product_description.product_id=es_product_to_category.product_id LEFT JOIN es_product ON es_product_description.product_id = es_product.product_id WHERE es_product_to_category.category_id = $subcategory_id AND es_product.status=1";
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($sql_subrec);
    $sub_product = $conn->query($sql_subrec);   
    while ($prow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_product)) {
      $subcategory_name['sub_category_name']['products_name'][] = $prow['prod_name'];
    }
  }

  //$subcategory_name[] = array('product_data' => $subcategory_name,);
  //echo "<pre>";print_r($subcategory_name);
  echo "<pre>";print_r($subcategory_name);      
}
```

Result is not coming as expected.

I want to get products inside related subcategory array but it is coming everything in first array.

```
Array
(
    [sub_category_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Weighing Scale
            [products_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => BS-250 Baby Scale
                    [1] => DS-415N Bench Scale
                    [2] => DS-415N Platform Scale
                    [3] => DS-65 Counter Scale
                    [4] => DS-852 Weighing Scale
                    [5] => DS-252 Weighing Scale
                    [6] => DS-215N Platform Scale
                    [7] => DS-75 Counter Scale
                    [8] => DS-415 Smile
                    [9] => DS-215SS Platform Scale
                    [10] => DS-450 Table Top Weighing Scale
                    [11] => DS-450SS Bench Scale
                    [12] => DS-451HP Weighing Scale
                    [13] => DS-215 Hanging Scale
                    [14] => DS-215N Trolley Scale
                    [15] => DS-673 Weighing Scale
                    [16] => DS-315 Series Crane Scale
                    [17] => DS-515 Weighing Scale
                    [18] => DS-450CW Check Weigher Scale
                    [19] => DC-810 Counting, Barcode Printing Scale
                    [20] => DC-85 Counting Scale
                    [21] => DS-252C Counting Scale
                    [22] => DC-810 Counting, Barcode Printing Scale
                    [23] => SI-810 Label Printing Scale
                    [24] => SI-810PR Receipt Printing
                    [25] => DS-252PR Receipt Printing Scale
                    [26] => Barcode Label Printer Scales
                    [27] => Receipt Printer Scales
                    [28] => SI-810PR Barcode Label Printer Scale
                    [29] => SM - 100EV+ Barcode Label Printer Scale
                    [30] => SI-810PRSS Receipt Printer Scale
                    [31] => SI-810PR Receipt Printer Scale
                    [32] => DS-252PR Receipt Printer Scale
                    [33] => DC-810 Counting, Barcode Printing Scale
                    [34] => SI-810 Label Printing Scale
                    [35] => DS-451TW Tank/Vessel Weighing
                    [36] => DS-451 Milk Weighing
                    [37] => SI-810 System Scale Bench Type
                    [38] => SI-810 System Scale Platform Type
                    [39] => HT-HTR Series Analytical Balance
                    [40] => MX-50 Moisture Analyzer
                    [41] => AJ Series Precision Balance
                    [42] => PG/FB Precision Balance
                    [43] => DS-852G Precision Balance
                    [44] => LF-225DR Semi-micro balance
                )

            [1] => Industrial Counting Scale
            [2] => Retail Printer Scale
            [3] => Weighing System & Solutions
            [4] => Weighing Balance
        )

)
```

Comment: What you have in your comments seems to be right... What's the problem?

Comment: You may use array_merge(); in php

Comment: can you post your actual output and what you want to achieve... I'm a little confused about what you want.

Comment: is the above what you want or what you get?

Comment: about ouput shows that all product names coming in to first subcategory array what I want is subcategory 1 => related products, sucategory 2=> related products,  sucategory 3=> related products etc.

Comment: @Daniel No I want like below,   subcategory 1 => related products, sucategory 2=> related products, sucategory 3=> related products what am getting is subcategory 1, all products array, subcategory 2,subcategory 3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from you limited explanation you might just need to do something like this in your second `while`:

```
$subcategory_name['sub_category_name'][$row['sub_cat_name']]['products_name'][] = $prow['prod_name'];
```

But this is just a guess... please post the expected output and the actual one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 'Sub Category Name' & 'Product Name' comes under single 'Sub Category ID' keyindex

```
if ($sub_category->num_rows > 1){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sub_category)){
            $subcategory_id = $row['sub_cat_id'];
            $subcategory_name[$subcategory_id]['sub_category_name'][] = $row['sub_cat_name'];
            $sql_subrec = "SELECT es_product_description.name AS prod_name FROM es_product_to_category LEFT JOIN es_product_description ON es_product_description.product_id=es_product_to_category.product_id LEFT JOIN es_product ON es_product_description.product_id = es_product.product_id WHERE es_product_to_category.category_id = $subcategory_id AND es_product.status=1";
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($sql_subrec);
            $sub_product = $conn->query($sql_subrec);   
            while ($prow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_product)){
                    $subcategory_name[$subcategory_id]['products_name'][] = $prow['prod_name'];
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($subcategory_name);        
    }
```

Comment: Thx Daniel and ashok got the required ouput. We used daniels code since we required category name.